# Reverting puppeteer upgrade in cloud functions dependencies does not revert error that was caused by the upgrade

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have recently updated my cloud functions to use puppeteer 19.0.
The previous working version was 18.2.1.

After updating, my functions threw an error:

```
Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (1045629)
```

There is an issue on the puppeteer repo where they advised to rollback to the latest working version and wait for the 19.1 version: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9128

My problem is that even with the downgraded version, my functions throw this error. I even deleted all my functions and redeployed them.

Is there some kind of dependency cache that I need to clear?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually installing puppeteer-core 18.2.1.

This usually gets installed as a co-dependency and did not downgrade from 19.0 to 18.2.1